# Can't access nested json elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm really stuck on how to access nested elements of a json response that I'm getting from my api.  I validated the json and it shows as valid.

For instance, how do I access the numFound attribute?  Here's my code that is not working:

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/SearchAPI/infopop?id=" + songID,
    datatype:"json",
    method: "get"
}).done(function (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj);                   /* This displays the entire json response 
    alert(obj.response.numFound)    /* This does not work
    alert(data.response.numFound)    /* This does not work
```

---

Here's the response I'm trying to access

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"off",
      "fl":"Name,Description,Keywords,ISRC,Instruments,Lyrics,Bpm,Vocal,Tempo,Key,TV_Genres,Music_Genres,length\r\n,Writers,profileImagePath\r\n,Publishers\r\n,songImagePath\r\n,Band_Styles",
      "start":"0",
      "callback":"?\r\n",
      "fq":[
        "id:00106c8c-7e21-4e75-80da-cdff8e6d3d44",
        "publicflag:1",
        "pubname:komposed"
      ],
      "rows":"10",
      "version":"2.2",
      "wt":"json"
    }
  },
  "response":{
    "numFound":1,
    "start":0,
    "docs":[
      {
        "profileImagePath":[
          "https://komposed.blob.core.windows.net/jrock-1873564a-d409-4370-80d8-23dc97114f18/songimage/f557110f-4ad3-4353-a1b3-3ba70d52e8f0?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=Q3ywrwEa6URp%2FPCvK0Ngesza8PBhMEmE5ONeKhw8vE4%3D&st=2016-06-16T16:49:45Z&se=2066-06-16T16:54:45Z&sp=r&rsct=application%2Foctet-stream&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dredneck.jpeg"
        ],
        "songImagePath":[
          "https://komposed.blob.core.windows.net/jrock-1873564a-d409-4370-80d8-23dc97114f18/songimage/f0c00dcd-69f9-42af-b236-4a53f0d78e76?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=oF0STMDddyuJiNZO%2BE78sYtbboC4ic%2Fl4bR5ESBFouE%3D&st=2016-06-16T16:48:59Z&se=2066-06-16T16:53:59Z&sp=r&rsct=application%2Foctet-stream&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3DTENSION%20LAST%20MAN.jpg"
        ],
        "Name":[
          "Bottle Service Tension"
        ],
        "Description":[
          "Cool crime scene track with a chill night club vibe"
        ],
        "Bpm":[
          90
        ],
        "Vocal":[
          "Acapella"
        ],
        "Tempo":[
          "Fast"
        ],
        "Writers":[
          "Justin Sirota|100.00|"
        ],
        "Keywords":[
          "club, crime, investigation, cool, lounge, pulse"
        ],
        "TV_Genres":[
          "Tension"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `obj.numFound`. `response` is your `data` argument.

```
$.ajax({
...
}).done(function (response) {
  alert(response.numFound)
...
```

Also, since you're telling jQuery (assuming this based on the code) that the response is of JSON type via `datatype:"json",` you don't need to do `JSON.parse` on it.

Comment: I did try that and get 'undefined'

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: "/api/SearchAPI/infopop?id=" + songID,
        datatype:"json",
        method: "get"
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert(response.numFound);
    });

Comment: Something doesn’t add up here. Based on what you’ve shown, it should have worked. At least one of yours or mine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumped, but think it must have something to do with the API.  Here's the scoop...  I'm calling Solr for search results.  It works just fine when I call solr directly from javascript using  $.getJSON(url);  I then am able to reference elements like you suggested.  But I've created a .NET API to do some config stuff then call Solr and pass the results back.  Below is the API code, in case you see something there.  Forgive me but I have coded in 6 years... ha!

Comment: using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

                    var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url.ToString())).Result;

                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);             
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
                }

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was in my API.  I was returning json as a string instead of an object.  Once I did that, javascript was able to reference the json elements. Thanks for trying to help!